# Need guidance with javascript error UnCaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, validation, forms, typeerror

I am having trouble with javascript I am using for a register form, I get the UnCaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null after this line of my javascript:

```
tf.value = tf.value.replace(rx, "");
```

and also after this line of javascript:

```
  var m = _("mobileNumber").value.length;
```

Here is my javascript and form:

```
<script>
    function restrict(elem){
    var tf = _(elem);
    var rx = new RegExp;
    if(elem === "email"){
        rx = /[' "]/gi;
    } else if(elem === "username"){
        rx = /^[a-z0-9]i*$/;
    } else if(elem === "mobileNumber"){
            rx = /^[0-9]*$/;
        }
    tf.value = tf.value.replace(rx, "");
}
function emptyElement(x){
    _(x).innerHTML = "";
}
function checkusername(){
    var u = _("username").value;
    if(u !== ""){
        ("unamestatus").innerHTML = 'checking ...';
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "signup.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) === true) {
              ("unamestatus").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
            }
        };
        ajax.send("usernamecheck="+u);
    }
}
function signup(){
    var u = _("username").value;
    var e = _("email").value;
      var m = _("mobileNumber").value.length;
    var p1 = _("pass1").value;
    var p2 = _("pass2").value;
    var ci = _("city").value;
      var pc = _("postcode").value;
      var c = _("country").value;
      var d = _("dateOfBirth").value;
    var g = _("gender").value;
    var status = _("status");
    if(u === "" || e === "" || p1 === "" || p2 === "" || c === ""
        || g === "" || m === "" || ci === "" || pc === "" || d === ""  ){
        status.innerHTML = "Fill out required fields";
    } else if(p1 !== p2){
        status.innerHTML = "Your password fields do not match";
        }else if(m !== 11 && !IsNumeric(m)){ 
        status.innerHTML = "Please enter valid mobile number";
         }else if(d === "dd/mm/yyyy"){ 
        status.innerHTML = "Please enter your date of birth";

    } else {
             //ajax to send form data to php
        //hides sign button
                _("signupbtn").style.display = "none";
        status.innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
                //wait until php verifies data
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "signup.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) === true) {
           //if sign not succesful unhide button
                    if(ajax.responseText !== "signup_success"){
                    status.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                    _("signupbtn").style.display = "block";
                } else {
```

FUNCTION

```
function _(x){
    return document.getElementById(x);
}
```

FORM

```
<form name="signupform" id="signupform" onsubmit="return false;">
    <div>Username: </div>
    <input id="username" type="text" onblur="checkusername()" onkeyup="restrict('username')"       maxlength="16">
    <span id="unamestatus"></span>
    <div>Email Address:</div>
    <input id="email" type="email" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" onkeyup="restrict('email')" maxlength="88">
    <div>Create Password:</div>
    <input id="pass1" type="password" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="16">
    <div>Confirm Password:</div>
    <input id="pass2" type="password" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="16">
     <div>First name:</div> 
     <input id="firstName" type="text"  /><br />
     <div>Last name:</div> 
     <input id="lastName" type="text"   /><br />
     <div>Mobile number*:</div>
     <input name="mobileNumber" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" onkeyup="restrict('mobileNumber')" maxlength="16">
    <div>Gender:</div>
    <select id="gender" onfocus="emptyElement('status')">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="Male">Male</option>
      <option value="Female">Female</option>
    </select>
    <div>Country:</div>
    <select id="country" onfocus="emptyElement('status')">
      <?php include_once("country_list.php"); ?>
    </select>
    <div>City:</div>
    <input id="city" onfocus="emptyElement('status')">
    <div>Postcode:</div>
    <input id="postcode" onfocus="emptyElement('status')">
    <div>Relationship Status*:</div>
    <select id="relationshipStatus" >
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Single">Single</option>
        <option value="Taken">Taken</option>            
                </select>
    <div>Date of Birth*:</div>
    <input id="dateOfBirth" type="date" onfocus="emptyElement('status')">
    <button id="signupbtn" onclick="signup()">Create Account</button>
    <span id="status"></span>
  </form>
```

Comment: The field `mobileNumber` has a name but not an id. If I recall correctly getElementById don't work with `name`, but must have an `id`.

Comment: I created an external js file I just added the _ function above, thanks

Comment: Ahh yes the id part should fix one of the errors thanks

Comment: In your `restrict`-function you have a lot of if-else-if... You could make that part much more readable with using `switch(elem) {case 'email': rx=/[' "]/gi; break; /*more code*/}`

Comment: You get the type-error because tf is null. tf is null because getElementById returns null. getElementById returns null because there isn't an element with the id you are trying to get. If you add a `console.log(elem,tf);` in your `restrict`-function you will quickly see what id returns null in the debug-console.

Comment: Thank you I have it fixed now, on my form the date of birth is of type date and it has a date picker would you have any tips for me to make sure a date is selected before submit?

Comment: Well, Joey, I'm g;ad you got it fixed. If @Some would make his comment an answer you can select it. As for your other question, you can ask another one, or check for a min date or default in the datepicker and fail validation if it equals one of those

Comment: @RichardBarker I could have written it as an answer, but it was not wort it at the time, when I wrote it more than two years ago. The answer from Andrea is also right, but have not got any votes during the last two years nor has it been accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, `tf` variable is null. Since you set the variable only when declaring it, it means that _(elem) return null.

In the second case, the function call _("mobileNumber") return null.

It's to possible to tell more if you don't post the `_` function

Comment: sorry I will update the question with the _ function